# Putting everything into a JFrame

Tags: java, jframe

I want to know how to put put console output into a JFrame. For example, putting this output into a JFrame:

```
import static java.lang.System.out;
```

public class frame{

```
public static void main(String [] args){  
        out.println("hello");
}
```

}

How is it possible?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/ refer this..

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is to broad too be answered here and better answers can be found by reading through the [Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/) tutorials

Answer (score 1):

**You need to set up the `JFrame` first.**

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("title");
```

**Then, set the properties of the JFrame:**

```
frame.setSize(1280,720); //Sets the program's size
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); //Tells the program to exit on close
frame.setResizable(true); //Tells the program if resizing is enabled
```

**Then, create a panel to store the components:**

```
JPanel p = new JPanel();
```

**After that, you must add the panel to the JFrame like so:**

```
frame.add(p);
```

**Then, with that done, you can use the components supplied in the swing framework, and add them to the panel. A reference for these components can be found here:** http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/componentlist.html.

**To create a component, use the following code:**

```
JLabel label = new JLabel();
```

**Then, use it's build in functions to change it:**

```
label.setText("new text");
```

**Then, once again, to add a component to a panel, use the panel's `add()` method:**

```
panel.add(label);
```

---

#### Those are just the basics of making a GUI with java. A full tutorial can be viewed here:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/

---

## Good Luck!

Comment: Sorry for the long answer! Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

1.If you want to use JFrame you have to extend your class to a subclass of `JFrame`:

```
public class frame extends JFrame {}
```

2.a)If you want to put Text in your Frame use `JLabel` and add it to your frame:

```
JLabel hello = new JLabel("Hello");
add(hello);
```

2.b)If you want a console output just call `System.out.println()` in the constructor

Here is a small example class:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class Frame extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new Frame();
    }
    Frame() {
        System.out.println("Hello");
        JLabel hello = new JLabel("Hello");
        add(hello);
        this.setSize(100, 100);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

have a look to the oracle lessons... or any java book!

Answer (score 0):

I can help you with this, but let me please fix some syntax errors you have. When you put the import, an import can't be static (that I know of) and when you want to print out something using "System.out.print" or "System.out.println" you MUST include the "System" part of the line. If you want to add text to a a JFrame use the JLabel to import both just do this bit of code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
```

That should import all of your swing elements such as JLabel and JFrame and JPanel, and try this code it will make a window that will have a button and a label. The button doesn't do anything in this code:

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class main{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {   
 /*
 * Creates the frame, makes it visible, and makes 
 * appear in the center of the screen. While also making it have a close operation
 */
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Button");
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setSize(300, 300);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

//Creates the panel, and adds it to the frame
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    frame.add(panel);

//Creates the label and adds it to the panel, also sets the text
    JLabel label = new JLabel();
    label.setText("Welcome" + "\n" + "\n");
    panel.add(label);

//Creates the button and adds it to the panel
    JButton button1 = new JButton("Button 1");
    panel.add(button1);

    }   
}
```

Comment: *"an import can't be static (that I know of)"* It can be. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/static-import.html

Comment: @Radiodef This is new to me, thank you for telling me.

Answer (score 0):

If that is the case, I don't want to get into GUI just yet. (Learning from a book) Can I convert my current project to a jar file and have it automatically open a command prompt window upon double click?